# Directory relative ZwCreateFile

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, driver, kernel-mode

I have to implement cross view file integrity checker for my University project. For that how do I list the files of a Directory in Kernel Mode??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your starting point would be [`ZwCreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - which has options such as "FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY".

You will then use [`ZwQueryDirectoryFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the information about the file(s) within that directory.

Make **SURE** that you are not forgetting to [`ZwClose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) after you open something - it's not so critical in a user-mode application that closes again after it's been used. But the kernel doesn't know when a driver stops using a file (or, for that matter, if some other driver has been given that filehandle, and will be using it at some point), so even if your driver is unloaded, files that it opened will remain open until the system restarts - I quite like to "not restart" my systems, and with a good set of drivers, running a machine for more than a year should be possible. If your driver so much as leaks one handle a day, that's 365 handles leaked.

So, the code would look something like this:

```
HANDLE h;
NTSTATUS status;
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES), NULL, L"mydir",
                         OPEN_CASE_INSENSITIVE, NULL, NULL };
IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb = {};

status = ZwCreateFile(&h, FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY, &oa, &iosb, NULL, 
                      FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, FILE_OPEN, FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE,
                      NULL, 0);
if (status != STATUS_SUCCESS)
{
   ... do something... 
   return errorcode;
}
else
{
    FILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION info;
    for(;;)
    {
        status = ZwQueryDirectoryFile(h, NULL, NULL, &iosb, &info, sizeof(info), 
                                      FileDirectoryInformation, TRUE, L"*.*",
                                      FALSE);
        if (status != STATUS_SUCCESS) 
        {
            ... check error code and perhaps print if unexpected error ... 
            break;
        }
        ... do soemthing with `info` ... 
    }
}
ZwClose(h);
```

This is just a "rough sketch". I don't have a setup to compile this right now, and I may have missed something important. But it should give you some idea. There are LOTS of optional parameters and optional choices here, and some I've "guessed" what you'd want, but I think I've made reasonable choices. There may be details missing that make this not work, but as a rough starting point, it should give you an idea at least.

Comment: No, I have used some of these features in a commercial product many years ago... But I will edit my post for some more info.

Comment: Sorry, without at least a more descriptive error than "c2220", not sure I can help - after what I can see c2220 is "Warning treated as error", so presumably there is a warning on the line, that you need to fix.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise? I'm afraid my plastic ball that I use as a cheaper version of a crystal ball doesn't "see" your code or your error message(s).

Comment: Something is seriously wrong with your includes in the main driver file. I'm not sure exactly what, and like I said, my Linux system that I'm using now isn't set up to build Windows drivers. If you step back and try to build just an empty driver, does it work?

Comment: Ok, so what did you change to make it stop compiling? Take it one step at a time. Compile often, write only a few lines at a time.

Comment: started when i added the "ntifs.h" ... for adding `FILE_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION ` and `ZwQueryDirectoryFile`

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the correct "ntifs.h"? I'm 99% sure that you shouldn't be including "winbase.h" from "ntifs.h"...

Comment: yup just rechecked ... that the point where it farts on my build screen =_="