# Windows Driver Listing Files to WinDbg Console

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, driver, kernel-mode

i'v already posted a question 
[question] : [Directory relative ZwCreateFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168129/directory-relative-zwcreatefile)

but i am unable to build the driver. I have posted the error as well. So i was wondering is there any other way to list files in a directory(kernel space) without using "ZwQueryDirectoryFile" routine.

Comment: Technically, there's `NtQueryDirectoryFile`, but it's essentially identical to `ZwQueryDirectoryFile`, so it's unlikely to be any real help.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't help further, but I'm not in a position to set up a dev machine with a DDK just to answer a question.

Comment: @Mats Peterson its ok,i was just trying to find a way around it. :D

Comment: If yours is driver is minifilter (or file system filter driver) preferred API is `FltQueryDirectoryFile()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543433(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Rohan : when i just include `fltkernel.h` for the `FltQueryFile().... my` build shows errors

Comment: you must to post full errors messages if you want help. I think you didn`t include flt manager static library to project -> fltMgr.lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rollup your oqn IRP : IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL/IRP_MN_QUERY_DIRECTORY, but this that ZwQueryDirectoryFile doing internally.